# How to exclude non alphabet characters from code?

Tags: python

```
#when I run it, it says something about a function discrimination being at 0x0E....

import string
import sys

code = raw_input("Enter your code: ")

translation = {"a": "d", "b": "e", "c": "f", "d": "g", "e": "h", "f": "i", "g": "j", "h": "k", "i": "l", "j": "m", "k": "n", "l": "o", "m": "p", "n": "q", "o": "r", "p": "s", "q": "t", "r": "u", "s": "v", "t": "w", "u": "x", "v": "y", "w": "z", "x": "a", "y": "b", "z": "c"}

lettered_code = list(code)

def translate(lettered_code):
    newanswer = ""
    for letters in lettered_code:
        newanswer += translation[letters]
    return newanswer

def checking(translate):
    return all((char in string.letters) for char in translate)

def discrimination(translate):
    if checking == False:
        print "Only letters!"
    else: 
        print translate(lettered_code)
    sys.exit()

print discrimination
```

Comment: Please format your code and post the **exact** error message.

Comment: `print discrimination(translate('asdf'))`

Comment: "function discrimination at 0x01E8D5F0"

Comment: This code is... very broken. I would consider working through the tutorial first.

Comment: you need parentheses after a function to call it.  You're just printing out the function object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isalpha` method to check if it's a letter

```
translation = {"a": "d", "b": "e", "c": "f", "d": "g", "e": "h", "f": "i", "g": "j", "h": "k", "i": "l", "j": "m", "k": "n", "l": "o", "m": "p", "n": "q", "o": "r", "p": "s", "q": "t", "r": "u", "s": "v", "t": "w", "u": "x", "v": "y", "w": "z", "x": "a", "y": "b", "z": "c"}

s = 'this is a test 123 that has numbers456 in the wr48ds'
newS = ''
for letter in s:
    if letter.isalpha():
        newS += translation[letter]
    else:
        newS += letter

>>> newS
'wklv lv d whvw 123 wkdw kdv qxpehuv456 lq wkh zu48gv'
```

Comment: I don't think he want's the numbers to get through, so maybe doesn't need the else statement to just add them to the new string... maybe else: print "Only letters!" and exit()

Answer (score 0):

Your `print discrimination` is printing the function object!

You should not be calling translate as a variable of discrimination...like so:

```
def discrimination():
    if checking == False:
        print "Only letters!"
    else: 
        print translate(lettered_code)
    sys.exit()


discrimination()  # don't need the print statement here either
```

But this will only get you so far... it works as long as you only enter letters...
You should consider redoing all these functions.